# writing a new column for the most frequent word in each row

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get the most frequent value or word in every row and add them in a new column

for example:

The original csv is called (stock.csv)

```
egg   meat     egg      lemon   
meat  orange   orange   egg
meat  meat     meat     orange
the new column will be added as follows


egg   meat     egg      lemon    egg    
meat  orange   orange   egg      orange
meat  meat     meat     orange   meat
```

as you can see the 5th column is added as the most frequent word that appears in that row (this is just an example , the actual csv contains almost 20000 row and almost 80 column)

This is my code , I know its a mess I'm just trying too hard to learn python and been working on this problem for 6 days now

```
egg = meat = lemon = orange =   0
freq ={ "egg":0 , "lemon":0 , "Spam":0 , "orange":0 }
with open('stock.csv') as csvfile:
    Myreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in Myreader:
        for i in row:
            if i == "Trojan":
                Trojan = Trojan + 1
                freq.update({'Trojan': Trojan})
              
            elif i == "egg":
                egg = egg + 1
                freq.update({'egg': egg})
            
            elif i == "meat":
                meat = meat + 1
                freq.update({'meat': meat})
            
            elif i == "orange":
                orange = orange + 1
                freq.update({'orange': orange})
            
            elif i == "lemon":
                lemon = lemon + 1
                freq.update({'lemon': lemon})
            
        max_key = max(freq, key=freq.get)
        with open('Most_Frequent.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_object:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            csv_writer = csv.writer(write_object)
            for row in csv_reader:
                row.append(max_key)
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
            write_object.close()
        egg = meat = lemon = orange =   0
```

the problem it just create a new csv file with only one useless row

plus: There are cells with the value "N/A"  that I don't want them to be counted because the are the dominant in every row

Comment: What should it do if 2 items have equal count? (e.g. `egg, egg, orage, orange`

Comment: use Counter to count items and get the most frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that:

```
from collections import Counter

rows = []
# build the new rows
with open('stock.csv') as csvfile:
    Myreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in Myreader:
        # most_common method returns a list of tuple of the form: (key, count)
        most_common_in_row = Counter(
            column for column in row if column.strip() != 'N/A'
        ).most_common(1)
        # make sure we haven't filtered all the columns in the row
        if most_common_in_row:
             most_common_in_row = [most_common_in_row[0][0]]
        # Not necessary, just to be explicit that if we filtered
        # the entire row, most_common_in_row is just an empty list
        # that adds nothing to the row
        else:
             most_common_in_row = []
        rows.append(row + most_common_in_row)
# write the new rows in the same file
with open('Most_Frequent.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: There are cells that contain the word "N/A" I don't want them to be counted because it will be the most frequent word in every row , how to deal with them ?

Comment: Look at the edited answer: You have to use a generator expression inside the Counter instantiation where you filter the values you do not want to take into account, in this case `'N/A'`

Comment: I tried the code but it still counts "N/A" value , I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Probably the problem is that 'N/A' has some white spaces around? I changed `if column != 'N/A'` to `if column.strip() != 'N/A'` in the answer to try if it helps

Comment: I got an error IndexError: list index out of range , what does mean ?

Comment: That means you have some empty rows in your csv file maybe. Added another filter to not pass empty rows to the counter

Comment: I have now put a more general method, please see the comments in the code. Thanks @swaroop for mentioning the possibility of filtering an entire row on 'N/A'

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using great `pandas` library with its `.mode()` method for that kind of task:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv')
df['most_frequent'] = df.mode(axis=1)
df.to_csv('Most_Frequent.csv')
```

Comment: I know about  it , its good but doesn't help in my case because I have cells that contains value "N/A" which I don't them to be counted

Comment: `.mode()` won't consider `NaN` values by default.

Comment: If your `N/A` values are actually a string, you can replace them with real `NaN`: `df = df.replace({'N/A': None})`

Comment: I got this error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: Can you show the snippet you are trying to run?

Comment: you mean the code or the dataset ? the code I just run the code above . and the dataset are almost 20000 row , and almost 80 column

Answer (score 0):

Using dict+sort:

```
import csv
csvfile = open('stock.csv')
Myreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
write_object = open('Most_Frequent.csv', 'w') 
csv_writer = csv.writer(write_object)
for row in Myreader:
    a = dict()
    for i in row: # Store count in a
        i == "N/A": continue
        if i not in a: a[i] = 0
        a[i] = a[i] + 1
    max = sorted(a.items(), key = lambda item:item[1], reverse=True)[0]
    row.append(max[0]) # max[0] is key, max[1] is value
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

write_object.close()
```

Comment: There are cells that contain the word "N/A" I don't want them to be counted because it will be the most frequent word in every row , how to deal with them ?

Comment: Updated to include the `N/A` handling.

Comment: I got an error with the syntax ,    i == "empty": continue
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Normally single statements in `if`-like blocks can be written inline. But if it is not working, add it in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not use any libraries. You can see all the steps involved in achieving what you need.

```
delimiter_character = ','

with open('stock.csv') as f1, open('updated_stock.csv', 'w+') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        # Construct the word counts dictionary
        word_count_dict = {}
        words = [word.strip() for word in line.split(delimiter_character)]
        for word in words:
            if word in word_count_dict:
                word_count_dict[word] += 1
            else:
                word_count_dict[word] = 1

        # Delete the occurrence of 'N/A' when there are other words
        if len(word_count_dict) > 1:
            del word_count_dict['N/A']

        # Identify the word with most repetitions
        most_frequent_words = sorted(word_count_dict, key=lambda w: word_count_dict[w], reverse=True)

        # Append the most frequent word
        words.append(most_frequent_words[0])
        f2.write(f'{delimiter_character}'.join(words) + '\n')
```

Comment: There are cells that contain the word "N/A" I don't want them to be counted because it will be the most frequent word in every row , how to deal with them ?

Comment: @ray I have edited the answer. If this is the requirement, you must also update your question with this detail.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about it , I edited it . so I got an error while trying to run your code IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @ray No problem, let me know if this solution is indeed working for you. I see that there are several solutions to your question. Don't forget to accept an answer that best serves your purpose. Good luck!

Comment: I got an error , IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The error might have occurred when you have a row with all values as `N/A`. In this case, we can append `N/A` to the end of the list. I have modified the code to reflect this scenario. Let me know, how it goes